# how to compute saliency map for an image in order to detect the object?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I am doing my project on saliency object detection in colour images. My question is how to generate or compute saliency map for an image because we need to compute probability map whether the pixel could be either object or background?
Q2.I have divided the image into superpixels and  How to calculate the distance between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need about saliency [here](https://ivrl.epfl.ch/research-2/research-current/research-saliency/). All state of the art research as of this date.

Comment: Thank you so much and I will go through it.@Stack player

Comment: select my answer if you find what you needed, that way others will also know!